# Why I can not open saved file using pickle

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, pickle

I saved a trained ANN model using pickle (as a .sav file). I was using the following script to open the file:

```
filename ='TuneMoveTrain24.sav'
trained_model = pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))
```

The code worked just fine but suddenly now I am getting the following error:

```
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5aa76a0b85f5> in <module>
      1 filename ='TuneMoveTrain24.sav'
----> 2 trained_model = pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))

5 frames
/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1334             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1335         if not endrec:
-> 1336             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1337         if self.debug > 1:
   1338             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

The file was created using the following snippet:

```
# Save the model
filename = 'TuneMoveTrain24.sav'
pickle.dump(best_model,open(filename,'wb'))
```

Any idea what's going on? Thank you.

I tried using different PC but no solution.

Link for SAV file :

```
https://github.com/dialectic/dia-navigation/blob/ab0bde01a8d7ceebb88fd93ad6f84831cc845dc6/TuneMoveTrain24.sav
```

Comment: What have you [looked into so far](https://github.com/araffin/rl-baselines-zoo/issues/109)? Please include all your research in your question.

Comment: Is the Python version of the writer the same as the one of the reader? Importantly, is the pickle protocol of the written files supported by the reader?

Comment: Impossible to answer since you did not include the code that creates the file too.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I have added the snippet in the actual post.

Comment: Is TuneMoveTrain24.sav a zip file?

Comment: @PierreD Tbh I didn't check  the python version while creating the file as I was using google colab. But now the colab python version is 3.8.

Comment: @nicomp negative! it's just a regular file with .sav extension.

Comment: Doesn't the error say raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")"" ?

Comment: @nicomp it never showed this error before. The code was working fine until couple of days ago started showing this error.

Comment: Your question teeters on being closed because you have not provided nearly sufficient information for us to reproduce your error .  If it stopped working, something changed. What changed? We can't know that.

Comment: @ARIF Perhaps you can provide a link to the .asv file for others to test.

Comment: @RicoPicone I have added a link to the .SAV file.

Comment: @ARIF I get the same error. I suspect the file is corrupted.